# How can i get the hasClass of click target?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$('.errorbox').click(function(event){
    console.log(event.hasClass('disabled'));
});
```

Anybody know why event is not returning the class of the item i am clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.errorbox').click(function(event){
    console.log(event.currentTarget.hasClass('disabled'));
});
```

Comment: `event.currentTarget` does not have the `hasClass` method.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the event handler refers the dom element to which the handler was registered to so you can check

```
$('.errorbox').click(function(event){
    console.log($(this).hasClass('disabled'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.errorbox').click(function(event){
    console.log($(event.target||event.srcElement).hasClass('disabled'));
});
```